# Unable to cast any string eg "0.8" to double in vb.net, using windows 8 pro 64x

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, .net-3.5

this is my first post ever. i have tried searching for an answer but i found nothing.

I seem to have a problem with windows 8 Pro, .Net 3.5 or a rights issue I suspect.
Using: Visual Studio 2010 ultimate

what i tried: re-installing .net

example code:

```
Dim test as String = "0.8"
Dim Value as Double
try
    value = test
catch ex as Exception
End Try
```

The error is receive "Conversion from string "0.8" to type 'Double' is not valid.

even if i use double.tryparse it does not convert "0.8" to a double or decimal.

IsNumeric Function is not even picking it up as a number?

Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you used Double.TryParse.  It should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are "Option strict On" in your code, replace it to this:

```
Option Strict Off
```

If you couldnt solve though tried this, 
You have no way but to CDbl() function.

```
value = CDbl(test)
```

Im a beginner of the Stack Ovrflow, too.
Lets ask and answer more!
*Im a japanese high school student, so there would be mistakes of English grammer or collocation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have tried all of the convert methods i could find.

But i have found the problem, for some reason inside the region and language settings (control panel) - additional settings - numbers the decimal symbol was set to a "," and I've been using a "." as the decimal symbol, once i changed that it worked like a charm.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I have no idea how to close this thread, but your answer is still ok, in code, i will mark that as the answer :)

Comment: @user3350039 - This is not sound advice.  Don't turn off Option Strict.  You're just asking for more headaches down the road.  Using Double.TryParse should have worked.  Can you show the code where you tried Double.TryParse?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - Youre right but i think I am right,  too. Many programmers were helped by automatic-convertion. Also many programmers were cried,too.